# Codeigniter 3 blog: how can I use the pagination from the index() method inside the search() method?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8. The posts are *paginated*. The application uses a `pagination.php` configuration file.

There is a search box for searching posts. I wish to *paginate the search results* and, since the methods `index()` and `search()` are in the same **Posts** controller, I am looking for a way avoid code redundancy by using the pagination inside `index()` for the search results too.

In the posts controller I have:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Static_model');
    $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    $this->load->model('Categories_model');
    $this->load->model('Comments_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url("/posts");
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
      $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($limit, $offset);
    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('posts');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
  }

  public function search() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('search', 'Search term', 'required|trim|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class = "error search-error"> ', ' </p>
      ');
      // If search fails
      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        return $this->index();
      } else {
        $expression = $this->input->post('search');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->search($expression, $limit, $offset);
        $data['expression'] = $expression;
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('search');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
      }
    }
  }
```

The **Posts_model** model has the code for both the *posts list* and the *search results*:

```
public function get_posts($limit, $offset) {
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}

public function search_count($expression) {
    $query = $this->db->like('title', $expression)
                  ->or_like('description', $expression)
                  ->or_like('content', $expression);
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    return $query->num_rows();  
}

public function search($expression, $limit, $offset) {
    $query = $this->db->like('title', $expression)
              ->or_like('description', $expression)
              ->or_like('content', $expression);
    $this->db->order_by('posts.id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

To be clear, I want to **avoid copying this** into the `search()` method:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
      $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I got stuck in my attempt to *borrow* the pagination from `index()` to `search()`.

What is missing?

Comment: You can't reuse the pagination from `index` to `search` (at least fully) since the base_url itself is should be different on each pagination. But you could reduce redundancy by specifying the static `$config` item that will be reused on constructor, like the `$config['per_page']` item, and then initialize the pagination on each method

Comment: @HastaDhana How would you do that? What's the optimal way to "borrow" the pagination? Consider the URL of search is `http://localhost/ciblog/posts/search`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:
- create a private method in controller and move paginator initialization code here
- call private method inside `index()` and `search()`

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Static_model');
    $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    $this->load->model('Categories_model');
    $this->load->model('Comments_model');
  }

  private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows) {
    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    //pass $totalRows param to pagination config
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
      $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

    return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
  }

  public function index() {
    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/posts", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

    //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('posts');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
  }

  public function search() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('search', 'Search term', 'required|trim|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class = "error search-error"> ', ' </p>
      ');
      // If search fails
      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        return $this->index();
      } else {
        $expression = $this->input->post('search');
        //call initialization method
        $config = $this->_initPagination("/search", $this->Posts_model->search_count($expression));
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

        //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->search($expression, $config['limit'], $config['offset']);
        $data['expression'] = $expression;
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('search');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I gt a `Call to undefined method Posts::_initPaginator()` error.

Comment: Sorry. I called a wrong method. It's `_initPagination`, not `_initPaginator`. I've changed it now. Thancks!

Comment: I have *1 search result* and the pagination has *as many items as the entire list of posts*.

Comment: Yes because you use `$this->Posts_model->get_num_rows()` in `_initPagination` method. You need to add a new parameter for `_initPagination` method for example `$totalRows` and replace the line `$config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();` with `$config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;`. In `index()` you need to call `$config = $this->_initPagination("/posts", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());` and in `search()` call `$config = $this->_initPagination("/posts", $this->Posts_model->search_count($expression));` but first you need to create a new method `search_count` in `Posts_model`

Comment: I have added the `search_count()` in the question. How should those methods look?